# ReflectionToStringBuilder in given format

Tags: java, string, reflection

I have a POJO representing a record in DynmaoDB table:

```
class Request{
       String id,
       String name,
       Status statusName,
       }
```

where Status is

```
public enum Status{
  OPEN, REVIEW, APPROVED }
```

I want to get the String representing the fields in a fixed format, just like

> Request_1  Name_1   OPEN
>
> Request_2  empty_string  APPROVED

empty_string represents an empty string which is used when the value of the field is not defined.
What I am doing now is

```
String requestRecord = this.toString(request);
```

where the `toString` method is :

```
public String toString(Request request) {
        return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(request, new RecursiveToStringStyle()).toString();
      }
```

This gives me the output like this :

> com.datamodel.Request@3bb5ceb[id=Request_1,name=,statusName=com.datatype.Status@2ffb3aec[statusName=Review,name=REVIEW,ordinal=1]]

Can anyone tell me how to get the string in the required format.?

Comment: @Tunaki I want to use the relection (and that too recursively) so that I can write all the values seperated by space. I think thats not answered there. Can you provide some reference?

Comment: You're confusing `toString()` that you override from `Object` with your `toString(Request request)`. The output you have comes from the former.

Comment: @Tunaki doesn't look like an attempt to override `toString()`, rather an external string-serialization method somewhere else

Comment: @zapl The problem is `Request request` that is missing its `toString()`. `ReflectionToStringBuilder` is built by giving the object directly as argument, so it will use the default `toString()` to print the object.

Comment: @Tunaki String requestRecord = this.toString(request); System.out.println(requestRecord);

Comment: @Tunaki it doesn't, it actually uses class.getName + system.identityHashCode() as part of the string style. You can write your own [`ToStringStyle`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringStyle.html), e.g. like the json one.